# No Report Items in toolbox (VS 2008 SP1)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, report, toolbox

I am using Visual Studio 2008 SP1 (version 9.0.30729.1). My problem is that the only reporting-related toolbox items I see are 3 "Textbox" controls. Where are the other stuff? Do I need to add a reference to a different assembly?

Here are the steps I take:
   1) Open Visual Studio
   2) Add new project --> "Reports Application"
   3) Open Report1.rdlc
   4) Open the toolbox and no controls are available (except the repeating 3 Textbox controls)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My good sense tells me that something got corrupted in your installation.

Here's what I would try before attempting a repair (this happened recently):

I fixed this by going into my profile as follows:

C:\Documents and Settings\MYUSERNAME\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\ProjectAssemblies

There are four HIDDEN files in there that make up what is apparently the toolbox cache.  If you erase them, they will be re-generated and #13119 will go back to General.  As I said, these files appear to be hidden so configure the file explorer accordingly.

Second problem: my User controls disappeared from the toolbox.
I was able to fix it by going into the VS menus:

Visual Studio "Tools" menu

"Options" submenu

"Windows Form Designer" tab 
"General" tab 
Set "AutoToolboxPopulate" to "True"

Comment: Thanks.  On Windows 7 I found the files in: C:\Users\kstricker\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\*.tbd

Answer (score 1):

My problem was The Report Items Toolbox was showing multiple textboxes instead of valid Report controls.
Solution: 
1) Close the visual studio 2005.
2) delete the folders under C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\application Data\microsoft\visualStudio\
3) Open your visual studio 2005 project. It should work

Answer (score 0):

Here is a book reference available through Google Books: http://books.google.com/books?id=b9j0MKXhnygC&pg=PA419&lpg=PA419&dq=vs+2008+Reports+Application+toolbox&source=web&ots=awTO1ibUZH&sig=7iHAUSCZ46_uAjC5lAfLeiXZt_Q&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=7&ct=result#PPA433,M1

I also did the same (on same VS2008 SP1) and had the exact same items available.

Answer (score 0):

A complete reinstall took care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!!

This fixed my report designer toolbox. My "report items" group was only showing three textbox items.

I am on Vista though, so the folder was..
C:\Users\Fox\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio

I just renamed this and next time VS started it recreated the toolbox and all the items were in place.

Before doing this I had tried to reset the toolbox with a "right-click|reset toolbox" in VS, but it didn't fix the problem, only removing this folder did it.